# upload file to CMSoctober show 0 byte - problem

Tags: php, html, forms, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

*I want to upload a file from a form, and in the CMS system it impresses me that the file is 0 bytes - I need help viewing the file *

html file:

```
{{ form_ajax('contactfrom::onSend', { files: 'true',  flash: 'true', 'data-request-files':true, 'data-request-validate': true }) }}
<form action="ContactForm.php" method="post" data-request="contactfrom::onSend" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-request-validate data-request-files>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Your name</label>
        <input type="name" name="name" id="yourName" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>file input</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="form-control-file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" multiple="multiple" />
    </div>

    <button align="right" type="sumbit" name="post" class="btn btn-success" value="Post" style="float: right;" ;>
        Create
    </button>
</form>
{{ form_close() }}
```

php file:

```
public function onSend() {
    
    $vars = [ 
      'name' => Input::get('name'),
      'file' =>Input::file('file'),
      'content'=> Input::get('content')
    ];

    $infri = new Infringement();
    $infri->name    = Input::get('name');
    $infri->file    = Input::file('file');
    $infri->save();    
}
```

and I put:

```
public $attachOne = [
    'file' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

and i see in my octoberCMS - file - 0 byte.
and if i try check the file :

```
if(Input::has("file")) {
    echo ", #>file";
} else {
    echo ", no file";
}
```

is return "#>file" .
please help.

Comment: I guess issue is, you added `form` tag twice `( form_ajax as well <form> )`. just remove inner form tag `<form action="ContactForm.php" method="post" ...` and it should start working other seems ok to me

Comment: i try , but still not working

Comment: can you share dumping output `dd($vars)` inside your `onSend` and inspect using dev tools and share us request output

Comment: [ 'name' => Input::get('name'),'email' => Input::get('email'),
                            'country' =>Input::get('country'),'url' =>Input::get('url'),
                            'message' =>Input::get('message'),'file' =>Input::file('file'),
                            'content'=> Input::get('content')];

Comment: i am not sure but its not dump of $var i think you are missing some thing it should be like 
['name' => 'name you input in textbox ' .... and so on` ']. like that

Comment: $infri = new Infringement();
                   
                    $infri->avatar  = Input::file('file');    but $var is just for the email.. i put that and i see 0 byte in CMS october

Comment: hmm are you sure you know how to use dump using `dd -> dump and die`  Laravel api, as given out-puts are not expected dumps

Comment: but in October writhing with this Label : $infri->avatar = Input::file('file'); from the form validate

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems author do not have knowledge of php or Laravel, so its pointless to start jumping in to CMS i guess